# How to load and use .ttf or any fonts in CosmosOS c#

Tags: c#, fonts, operating-system, truetype, cosmos

I'm trying to make an operating system with CosmosOS([Website](https://www.gocosmos.org/) [Github](https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos)) and I have static Fonts class where I have this:`public static Font Default = PCScreenFont.Default` which works perfectly but I wanted to load downloaded .ttf font like this: `public static Font *font_name* = new PCScreenFont(*width*, *height*, System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"*font_location*"), *unicode_mapping*);` but it don't work because I don't know how to map unicode characters. Can someone please help me? I was searching for clues for 2 days..

I have this: `public static Font Default = PCScreenFont.Default` which works
I tried this: `public static Font OpenSans = new PCScreenFont(16, 16, System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"../../../UI/Fonts/OpenSans.ttf"), null);` (Font is in UI/Fonts and the unicode mapping I don't have any clue how to do) which don't work

Answer (score 0):

You will need a TTF decoder. I think someone made one, you will get it if you ask for it in the [CosmosOS discord](https://discord.gg/5487JP5GuM)